# Azure SQL Server database - Deleting data

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am currently working on a project that is based on:

Azure EventHub1-->Stream Analytics1-->SQL Server DB

Azure EventHub1-->Stream Analytics2-->Document DB

Both SQL Server and DocumentDB have their respective Stream job, but share the same EventHub stream.

DocumentDB is an archive sink and SQL Server DB is a reporting base that should only houses 3 days of data. This is per reporting and query efficiency requirements.

Daily we receive around 30K messages through EventHub, that are pushed through Stream job (basic SELECT query, no manipulation) to a SQL Server table.

To preserve 3 days of data, we had designed a Logic App that calls a SQL SP that deletes any data, based on date, that is more than 3 days old. Runs every day at 12am.

Also, there is another business rule Logic App that **READs** from the SQL table to perform business logic checks. Runs every 5 mins.

We noticed that for some strange reason the Logic App for data deletion isn't working and data through months has stacked up to 3 Million rows. The SP can be run manually, as tested in Dev setup.

The Logic App shows ***Succeeded*** status, but SP execute step shows an Amber check sign, which when expanded says ***3 tries occurred.***

I am not sure why the SP doesn't delete old data. My understanding is that because Stream job keep pushing data, the Delete operation in SP can't get a Delete Lock and time out.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Azure Automation instead. Create a runbook that runs the stored procedure. [Here](https://blog.rdx.com/azure-automation-scheduling-stored-procedures/) you will find an example and step-by-step procedure.